# npm error for any package installing

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to install any node package e.g  `npm install -g grunt`the similar result showing

this is the output of a command: grunt-cli installing

```
E:\apps>npm install -g grunt-cli
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErr (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:88:11)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:99:9
npm ERR!     at Socket.onerror (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\https-proxy-agent.js:104:5)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:62:8)
npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErr (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:88:11)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:99:9
npm ERR!     at Socket.onerror (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\https-proxy-agent.js:104:5)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:62:8)
npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
npm ERR!   message: 'request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-04T13_17_42_467Z-debug.log

    npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
    npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
    npm ERR!     at emitErr (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:88:11)
    npm ERR!     at C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:99:9
    npm ERR!     at Socket.onerror (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\https-proxy-agent.js:104:5)
    npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:62:8)
    npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
    npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
    npm ERR!     at emitErr (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:88:11)
    npm ERR!     at C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\agent.js:99:9
    npm ERR!     at Socket.onerror (C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\https-proxy-agent.js:104:5)
    npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:62:8)
    npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    npm ERR!   message: 'request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80',
    npm ERR!   type: 'system',
    npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED' }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
    npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\RSA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-04T13_17_42_467Z-debug.log
```

Comment: looks like a connection issue. See if this URL resolves on your browser https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt

Comment: @ifiok for any pakage it shows this error I removed npmrc files content but nothig happens fine. I think it is related with : `reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: you must be behind a firewall that does not allow your machine to make the connection. Did the URL work on your browser?

Comment: I find that, it is because of a settings of application (I guess Antivirus) some variables are add to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment.